# Android Navigation Component - Navigating (with args) from one activity to a second, passing args of second activity to the startDestination fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a `StartActivity` and a `MainActivity`.

`StartActivity` is responsible for logging the user in.

`MainActivity` is responsible for everything the user can do after they are logged in.

I'm wanting to use the relatively new Navigation Components (nav graphs, nav controllers etc).

It's been quite hard to find some official Google documentation on how to setup multi-activity applications using Navigation Components. All their "How to get started" documentation assumes a single activity application, with multiple fragments where you navigate between the fragments.

But as stated above, my use case is slightly different. I want to be able to use navigation components to navigate between activities. Each of my 2 activites layouts has a `FragmentContainerView` as `NavHostFragment`, and each has it's own associated nav graph XML file.

I am also attempting to use `SafeArgs` to pass arguments around.

Here is the nav graph for my `StartActivity`'s `NavHostFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/start_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_start">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_start"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.start.StartFragment"
        android:label="@string/label_start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_main"
            app:destination="@id/nav_main" />
    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/nav_main"
        android:name="com.example.ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_main_activity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="long"
            app:nullable="false" />

    </activity>

</navigation>
```

So, the idea here is, from the `StartFragment` you can navigate to the `MainActivity`. `SafeArgs` is generating a class called `StartFragmentDirections` with a static method `navigateToMain(id: Long)` (with the argument for this call coming from the `<argument>` element in the `<activity`> element with the id `nav_main`). I call this static method when the user has logged in, providing the users id as the argument.

This works fine, my `MainActivity` is fired up and, I can access the arguments in `onCreate` via the `SafeArgs` delegate property which I've declared as a private field on the class like so:

```
private val args: MainActivityArgs by navArgs()
```

So far, so good.

Here is the nav graph for my `MainActivities`'s `NavHostFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_main"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/label_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="long"
            app:nullable="false" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

The idea here being that the start destination for the `MainActivity`'s `NavHostFragment` will be the one with id `nav_main` - which in this case is `MainFragment`. Now, as we can see, `MainFragment` also has an `<argument>` element, meaning that SafeArgs are generated for the `MainFragment`. Therefore, I figured, I could use the delegated SafeArgs property in my `MainFragment` like so:

private val args: MainFragmentArgs by navArgs()

This compiles fine (expected - SafeArgs is presumably just generating the classes based on what is described in the nav graph XML files...). However, when I run the app it crashes and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idlegod/com.example.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        ....
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:34)
```

This wasn't *super* surprising to me - I mean my nav graph for my `StartActivity'`s `NavHostFragment` does have the `MainActivity` as the destination, not the `MainFragment`. However, I am now completely stumped about how I'm supposed to navigate from one activity to another, passing data along and having that data propogate to the so called `startDestination` of the second activites `NavHostFragment`s nav graph...

I know how to do this the "old school" way (intent + extras + pulling extras out in onCreate etc) but I thought the whole point of this Navigation Components architecture was to remove all that clutter from the code and do things in a more declarative way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think if you are passing args from one activity/navGraph to another you have to specify the navGraph of the NavHostFragment programatically (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#pass_activity_destination_args_to_a_start_destination_fragment)